# Texture paint stroke

Tags: texture-painting

How can I avoid repetition of the drawn stroke?
Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't draw on the image itself, instead paint the line on another image texture that has a transparent background and mix the 2 images through a *MixColor*. Set your new *Image Texture* to *Clip* instead of *Repeat*. Plug an *Input > UV Map* into this new *Image Texture*, give a new UV map to your object, unwrap again in order to correctly place your line over the background, select this new UV map in the *UV Map* node:

[image]

Comment: WOW! 
This is a good method if i want apply a single texture, for example a decal, so thank you very much!

But, if i want draw with a personal brush using texture paint?

Comment: Yes you can, just create a new image with the Alpha at 0 (or you can still get a transparent background with the Draw brush in Erase Alpha mode)